# MySQL db isn't populating

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a register/login html/php script. I created a database and I believe my html/php code is correct. I was wondering if I am missing something small. Here is my code so far.

Here is the database

```
<?php
         error_reporting(E_ALL);
         ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
        $User = "**"; 
        $Password = "**";
        $Database = "member";
        $Host = "localhost"; 
        $con = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($con,$Database);
        $myusername = $_POST["username"];
        $mypassword = $_POST["password"];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO member (username, password) VALUES ('$myusername','$mypassword')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        mysqli_commit($con);
        mysqli_close($con);

        echo "Thank You! Information entered.";
        }
else
        {
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="proInput.php">
        Username:<input type="Text" name="username"><br>
        Password:<input type="Text" name="password"><br>
        <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Register"></form>
        <?
        }
?>
```

Every time I type `SELECT * FROM member;` in MySQL my database is empty.

Comment: this may be obvious but is there records in the db?

Comment: Nope my db is empty. I am new to creating databases too. Did I create my db incorrectly?

Comment: Try `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`

Comment: It's still showing Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: what's the name of the php file?

Comment: this current one is proInput. After I click the submit button I want the page to go to my login page. main_login.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you answered already in your comment,

the name of the file isn't main_login.php but proinput.php

Your form is posting it's data to main_login.php and I'm assuming you don't have the insert query on that page, your code isn't run at all.

Options:

1. Try changing the name of this php file to main_login.php and then instead of the echo redirect the user to the login page
2. Move this part of the insert to your main_login.php

   ```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
       {
       $User = ""; 
       $Password = "";
       $Database = "member";
       $Host = "localhost"; 
       $con = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
       if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
       mysqli_select_db($con,$Database);
       $myusername = $_POST["username"];
       $mypassword = $_POST["password"];
       $sql = "INSERT INTO member (username, password) VALUES ('$myusername','$mypassword')";
       mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       mysqli_commit($con);
       mysqli_close($con);




       echo "Thank You! Information entered.";
       }
       else
       {
       ?>
   ```
3. for debugging add the following to the very top of your php file right after the opening of php

   ```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
   ```

**This worked for me**

```
  <?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

  if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
    $User = "db_user"; 
    $Password = "db_password";
    $Database = "db_name";
    $Host = "db_host"; 
    $con = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,$Database);
    $myusername = $_POST["username"];
    $mypassword = $_POST["password"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO member (username, password) VALUES ('$myusername','$mypassword')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    mysqli_commit($con);
    mysqli_close($con);

    echo "Thank You! Information entered.";
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="proinput.php">
    Username:<input type="Text" name="username"><br>
    Password:<input type="Text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Register"></form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Just updated my proInput.php. file. My database still isn't populating. I must be overlooking something simple.

Comment: please check the debugging option and reply with the error

Comment: is your db called member and your table also called member?

Comment: Yep I double checked. I really have no idea why this isn't populating my datebase. Would the error show up on the screen?

Comment: if you add the error reporting as I suggested you should se the error on screen

Comment: Nothing appeared. I am going to create a new database and create a new .php code. Maybe I just spelt something wrong in my database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94884/discussion-between-davejal-and-cory).

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqli_commit($con);
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
```

You're committing *before* you insert, and then closing an uncommitted transaction. Try swapping the first two lines in the above excerpt.

Comment: It still didn't populate my datebase. =(

Comment: Looks like you're still leaving out the commit.That's the step that tells the dbms to save the insert.

Comment: Just fixed it. I left it out for some reason. It's still not populating with the commit code. Sorry about that.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_commit()` both return success or failure. If one of those is actually failing a call to `mysqli_error()` should prove informative.

Answer (score 1):

please add 'or die (mysqli_error())'  at the end of your query and get the sql error report. That should tell you what is exactly wrong with sql . Php error reporting will only give php errors.

Comment: I assigned $Database incorrectly. I was able to connect to MySQL correctly but I thought $Database was suppose to be the name of my table. I changed my $Database and everything works now. Thank you everyone for all the help.